# Rails check if relationships exist in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new with ruby on rails and I'm blocked on a big problem. I create a User table and a Course table. A user if he is a student can register to a Course. So i have my join table which is courses_users with the id of my User and the id of my course.

In a view I displayed all my courses and with them i have a "register" button for each different course :

```
<%= button_to 'register', modules_path, method: :post, params: {course_id: course.id, user_id: current_user.id} %>
```

And this gonna call my method Create :

```
def create
    @course_user = CoursesUser.new(course_params)
    @course_user.save
    redirect_to modules_path
end
```

So this will create my relation between the current user and the course_id I selected.

My problem is that how should I do to catch my relation and if this one already exist it will display an other button to Unregister from this course (similar to a follow / unfollow)

I tried with this :

```
@course_user = CoursesUser.where(user_id: current_user.id)
```

but i dont know how to make a condition in my view.

I dont know if i'm precise enought but if someone know how to solve it, it would be really nice !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have an association in user.rb

```
User has_many :courses
```

Now you can get the list of user courses

```
<% if current_user.course_ids.include?(course.id) %>
  <%= button_to 'unregister', ....  %>
<% else %>
  <%= button_to 'register', modules_path, method: :post, params: {course_id: course.id, user_id: current_user.id} %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

if your `@course_user` instance returns the value you expect
then your view should look like

```
<% if @course_user.blank? %>
 <%= button_to 'register', modules_path, method: :post, params:  course_id: course.id, user_id: current_user.id} %>
<% else %>
 #your unregister/unfollow link
<% end %>
```

Good luck.