# ruby check if data exist in database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Im new with ruby on rails and I'm again blocked on something really similar as the last time.. I have a User table, a Course table and a Mark table.
I can create a Mark with a user_id, a course_id and a grade.

In my models i have :

```
/* Mark model */
class Mark < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :course
end

/* Course model */
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :marks
end

/* User model */
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :marks
end
```

So what I want to do is when I created a new mark, with my form I want that my form disappear and display a button destroy ! Like this :

```
<% if @mark.course_ids.include?(@course.id) and @mark.user_ids.include?(user.id)
   # Button destroy
<% else %>
   <%= form_for Mark.new do |f| %>
       <%= hidden_field_tag :course_id, @course.id %>
       <%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, user.id %>
       Grade: <%= number_field_tag :grade, nil, min: 0, max: 100 %>
       <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The goal is to avoid the form when the mark just be added previously..
But here obviously @mark.course_ids and @mark.user_ids doesn't exist !!

Thanks for you help !

Comment: _"similar as the last time"_ – are you referring to another question? If so, provide a link, please.

Comment: Yes the other one was this : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348313/rails-check-if-relationships-exist-in-database)

Comment: `@mark` contains `course_id` and `user_id`. So you may write `if @mark.course_id == @course.id && @mark.user_id == user.id`

Comment: @Velantin Mark belongs to user and Mark belongs to course . it means Mark will always have only one course and user. right ?

Comment: My view will be a show on my course so example : course/1. I find the `@mark` by making a findall where `course_id: params[:id]` ! This is to get every `@mark` in my table link to this course. So `@mark` is a table and can't call method `user_id` or `course_id` without a `.each` !

Comment: @Vishal No a User can have 1 mark per course and a course 1 mark per user ! So maybe i'm doing the wrong way ! I didn't really get the difference maybe :/

Comment: It like : my Course is **Maths** and I want to add a mark to **Valentin**

But **Valentin** can't have two different mark in this course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A belongs_to association sets up a one-to-one connection with the other models. Rails then creates a singular utility method (among others) in your model.

For example, According to your model associations, a Mark **belongs_to** a Course and a User. Rails will create the following utility methods in your Mark model:

```
@mark.course
@mark.user
```

So the statement:

```
@mark.course_ids.include?(@course.id) and @mark.user_ids.include?(user.id)
```

is incorrect. Those methods do not exist in the Mark model.

Try this:

**Controller**

```
@marks = Mark.where(course_id: params[:id])
```

This will get all the marks for that course so the mark will definitely have a course associated with it (there's no need to make that check in your view).

**View**

Render a form for each mark:

```
<% @marks.each do |mark| %>
  <% unless mark.user.exists? %>
    <%= form_for Mark.new do |f| %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag :course_id, @course.id %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, user.id %>
      Grade: #{number_field_tag :grade, nil, min: 0, max: 100}#{f.submit}
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer ! But If i want to use @mark.course for exemple, what shoul i have in my controller? Actually I have this `@mark = Mark.where(course_id: params[:id])` but this is an array :/

Comment: @ValentinFerey .where will always return a collection of records. Also, a single course can have multiple marks so it makes sense that it returns an array of marks for the course. You have to loop through each one and display a form for it. Check my updated answer.

Comment: WoooW ! Thanks a lot !! Of course I new that was the only solution but I just didn't know about the "Unless" tag ! With this I can fix all my problems ! Thanks a lot ! I never heard about unless before ROR ...

Answer (score 1):

First, I suggest you rethink your tables, maybe take a look at the many-to-many relationship.

Regarding your question, you want to know if there exists a mark that belongs to a specific course for a specific user, so you would need something like this :

```
Mark.where(course_id: @course.id, user_id: current_user.id).any?
```

This will return true if such a record exists.

Comment: This could work but my User_id is not the current_user ! This is a id of every user in this course this need a .each method ...